# Multiple class inheritance not working - Class(A, B) and super() only returns values from class A and not B

Tags: python, python-3.x, super

[CONTEXT]
I created an API (personal project) to parse a top100 billboard based on a date and create a top10 playlist in my spotify.
It is working when my main is simple.
It is no more working when I create my main with class and call super() on sub classes

[ERROR]
Error:
`self.sp.user_playlist_create(user=self.userid, name=playlistname, public=False, AttributeError: 'Main' object has no attribute 'sp'`

[FINDINGS]
Multiple inheritance is not working.
I get all self values from Scraper, but not from SpotifyConnect.
ex: self.tracks is recognised in Main but self.sp is not in Main.

[CODE]

- module website_scraper.py (working as standalone)
  `

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


class Scraper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = input("Please enter the hit date in format YYYY-MM-DD: \n")
        self.response = requests.get(url="https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/"+self.date).text
        self.tracks = None
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.response, features="html.parser")

    
    def list_tracks(self):
       l = [i.getText().strip() for i in self.soup.find_all(class_="u-max-width-230@tablet-only")]
       self.tracks = [f"{l[i + 1]} - {l[i]} " for i in range(0, len(l) - 1, 2)]
       # Just give the top10
       return self.tracks[:10]
```

- module Spotify.py (working as standalone as well)
  `

```
import spotipy, dotenv, pprint
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

SCOPE = "playlist-modify-private, playlist-modify-public, playlist-read-private"
SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID = dotenv.get_key(key_to_get="SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID", dotenv_path=".env")
SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET = dotenv.get_key(key_to_get="SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET", dotenv_path=".env")
SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI = dotenv.get_key(key_to_get="SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI", dotenv_path=".env")


class SpotifyConnect:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_uri = None
        self.playlist_id = None
        self.sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(scope=SCOPE,
                                                            client_id=SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID,
                                                            client_secret=SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET,
                                                            redirect_uri=SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI))
        self.userid = self.sp.me()["id"]

    def create_playlist(self, playlistname: str):
        self.sp.user_playlist_create(user=self.userid, name=playlistname, public=False,
                                     description="Created by Python API from top100 billboard")
        # below to retrieve newly created playlist ID
        for listing in SpotifyConnect().sp.current_user_playlists()["items"]:
            if listing["name"] == playlistname:
                self.playlist_id = listing["id"]

        # adding tracks from the billboard, it needs a list to be passed in items (not a str even if single track)
        self.sp.playlist_add_items(playlist_id=self.playlist_id,
                                   items=self.list_uri)

    def convert_tracks_to_sp_uri(self, list_tracks: list) -> list:
        self.list_uri = [SpotifyConnect().sp.search(element)["tracks"]["items"][0]["uri"]
                         for element in list_tracks]
        return self.list_uri
```

- initial main.py (working)

```
from website_scraper import Scraper
from spotify_api import SpotifyConnect


new_dict_top100 = Scraper()
new_spotify = SpotifyConnect()
new_spotify.convert_tracks_to_sp_uri(list_tracks=new_dict_top100.list_tracks())
new_spotify.create_playlist(f"Top 10 from {new_dict_top100.date[-2:]}/{new_dict_top100.date[5:-3]}/{new_dict_top100.date[:4]}")
```

- new main.py (not working)

```
from website_scraper import Scraper
from spotify_api import SpotifyConnect


class Main(Scraper, SpotifyConnect):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.list_tracks()
        self.convert_tracks_to_sp_uri(self.tracks)
        self.create_playlist(f"Top 10 from {self.date[-2:]}/{self.date[5:-3]}/{self.date[:4]})")

## edit: removed below as per first comment ###
    def list_tracks(self):
        super().list_tracks()

    def convert_tracks_to_sp_uri(self, list_tracks: list):
        super().convert_tracks_to_sp_uri(list_tracks)

    def create_playlist(self, playlistname: str):
        super().create_playlist(playlistname)
####################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    new_playlist = Main()
```

Comment: ... your overrides in `Main` do nothing. Simply remove them. Subclasses do *not* have to re-define all methods. You only have to redefine methods that must change behaviour. Anyway, without an actual stack trace it's hard to understand what the problem is. IMHO: `super` has literally nothing to do with an error mentioning "list out of range"...

Comment: @Bakuriu
I modified the code to remove "-" in list_tracks() in Scraper.

The error I am getting now:
```self.sp.user_playlist_create(user=self.userid, name=playlistname, public=False,
AttributeError: 'Main' object has no attribute 'sp' ```